# If a vector $2i + 3j + 8k$ is perpendicular to the vector $4 j- 4i + αk $ then the value of α is? solve without using the property of dot product.

Tags: vectors

If a vector $2i + 3j + 8k$ is perpendicular to the vector $4 j- 4i + αk $, then the value of α is .

- Q is to solve this question without using the property of dot product.

From dot product ( How I solved it )

$2(4)+3(-4)+8(α) = 0 $. From here , we get α = +$\frac{1}{2}$

I want to know more different ways of how can I solve this Q.

Comment: You've been here long enough to know it's customary to format posts with MathJax on this site.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you for your feedback. What else do you think now needs to be mathjaxed?

Comment: While other methods might be possible (e.g. cross product), dot product really is the way to go here! That is to say, you shouldn’t hope to find anything better/simpler/more natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the two vectors are perpendicular, a less natural way would be think of Pythagoras theorem

Let $\vec {AB}=2i+3j+8k$ and  $\vec {AC}=-4i+4j+\alpha k$

Since $\vec {AB} \perp\vec{AC} $, Therefore we have $\vec{BC}=\vec{AC}-\vec{AB}=-6i+j+(\alpha-8)k$

Also $BC^2=AC^2+AB^2$

$(-6)^2+(1)^2+(\alpha-8)^2=(16+16+\alpha^2)+(4+9+64)$

$\alpha=-0.5$

Comment: The correct answer is $-0.5$ and $0.5$

Comment: Here. Let us say AB vector = 4i and AC vector = 2j. They are perpendicular to each other. Now , ahead of AC and AB is at point C and B. Then , Why did you take BC and not CB ?.h

Comment: Oh. Magnitude is still same. Got it.

Comment: @S.M.T If my answer helped you, please accept it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Pythagorean theorem. If you add two vectors, you get $6i-j+(8+\alpha)k$. Then we have $36+1+(8+\alpha)^2=4+9+64+16+16+\alpha^2 \implies 16\alpha=8$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\uvec}[1]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\textbf{#1}}}}$
You can use cross product.

As we know $|\vec p × \vec q|=|\vec p| |\vec q| \sin{\theta} \tag{i}$ , where $\theta$ is the angle between vectors $\vec p$ and $\vec q$.

Let $\vec p= 2 \uvec i + 3\uvec j +8 \uvec k$ and $\vec q= 4 \uvec i - 4 \uvec j +\alpha \uvec k$

Given that $\vec p$ and $\vec q$ are perpendicular, $\theta= 90° \implies \sin{\theta}=1$

Now, $\vec p × \vec q=\begin{vmatrix}
\uvec i & \uvec j& \uvec k\\
2 & 3 & 8\\
4 & -4 & \alpha
\end{vmatrix}$
$=(3 \alpha +32) \uvec i - (2 \alpha -32) \uvec j +(-8-12)\uvec k$

$\therefore |\vec p ×\vec q|=\sqrt{(3 \alpha +32)^2  + (2 \alpha -32)^2+20^2}$
$$|\vec p|= \sqrt{2^2+3^2+8^2}=\sqrt{77}, |\vec q|= \sqrt{4^2+(-4)^2+{\alpha}^2}$$
Using (i) we get,

$\sqrt{(3 \alpha +32)^2  + (2 \alpha -32)^2+400}=\sqrt{77(32+{\alpha}^2)}$

Solve for $\alpha$

Comment: Forbidding the use of the dot product is odd enough. But using the cross product instead borders on the deranged!

Comment: @TonyK the OP wanted to know different ways. He didn't say anything about the complexity  or preciseness of the other method.